# "Module not found: can't resolve..." with React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, module

I'm new to it, seems like a simple issue but I can't figure out why is my React app breaking with this error. I've even copied the whole source file and pasted, but still have this going on. What could be some the reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, that's usually two issues: Either your Node.js is outdated when it comes to importing libraries, or you are importing a local file using a wrong path. I suggest you changing paths until you get it right.

Comment: Thank you. Solved it by changing the import path until it clicked. My file was structured differently from the source code I'm studying, hence why.